# Magento 2.2 : New features for Community Edition

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento-community

I am looking for new features that have been added for Magento 2.2 CE since 2.1.x and whether or how will it change anything major for Magento developers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The below is all for Magento Open Source, formerly known as Magento Community

Release notes for 2.2 and other versions can be found in the Magento Devdocs

Here is the highlights excerpt from the release notes

Magento Open Source 2.2.0 includes a wealth of new, exciting features, and hundreds of enhancements and fixes. Look for the following highlights in this release:

- **Bundled extensions**. This release of Magento includes the first third-party extension that we are bundling with Magento Commerce –
  Magento Social. This extension establishes a connection between your
  store and your corporate Facebook account, and creates a page with
  products from your catalog. When shoppers click a product, they are
  redirected to the corresponding product page in your Magento store.
- **Significant enhancements in platform security and developer experience**. Security improvements include the removal of
  unserialize calls and protection of this functionality to increase
  resilence against dangerous code execution attacks. We have also
  continued to review and improve our protection against Cross-Site
  Scripting (XSS) attacks.
- **Upgraded technology stack**. We’ve dropped support for PHP 5.6, and Varnish 3. We now support PHP 7.1 Varnish 5, and MySQL 5.7. All
  third-party libraries have been upgraded to the latest stable
  version.
- **Pipeline deployment**, a new deployment process, enables build and deployment stages to minimize production system downtime for site
  updates. Resource-intensive processes can run on the build server.
  Pipeline deployment supports easy management of configuration between
  environments, too. Read more about pipeline deployment here.
- **Performance gains from improvements in indexing, cart, and cache operations.** Customers can browse and shop on a storefront while
  indexers are running with no visible impact to their experience.
  Additionally, long-running indexers operate in batches to better
  manage memory and run times. Cart improvements enable a buyer to
  create a cart with more than 300 line items, and merchants can
  process a cart with at least 300 line items. Varnish cache
  configuration now includes saint and grace mode to ensure Varnish is
  always presenting a cached page to a shop’s customers. Enhancements
  to cache invalidation logic and optimization of edge side include
  blocks for frequently changing data that significantly boost cache
  hit ratios.
- **Substantial contributions from our Community members.** Our Community Engineering Team has been working with skilled and
  enthusiastic community members, and together they’ve added hundreds
  of pull requests to the Magento code base. For more information about
  our Community Engineering Team. see Magento Community Engineering.

More here [Dev Docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.2.0CE.html)

Magento 2.1.X release notes can be found here [Dev Docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/release-notes/release-notes.html)

Comment: I am tempted to accept the answer but it doesn't answer second part - > whether or how will it change anything major for Magento developers?

Comment: Hey Neo sure i understand that. I am not 100% sure how deep someone can answer this here in this form. From a recent conference I attended I can say though that the certifications for Magento developers are coming based on 2.3 and 2.4 so I think there might be some changes for developers to handle before that. Sorry that i cant say more than this.